# What span should a staff "Report Card" cover?

Tags: user-research, information-architecture

I am tasked to create an enterprise level “Report Card” for help tickets processed by staff.  There are a few hundred groups, and so the report would have a user selected parameter to select a group and a date parameter.  Results would be for each staff member in the group.  All of the data is freely available in the ticket engine, there are no significant privacy concerns (in house), anyone would be able to view the report but the target audience is first line management.

I have a couple of similar requests from differing areas of a large organization, and I have established KPI (Key Performance Indicators) reports based on industry standards that would be benchmark for each metric.  Each KPI is a unique report,

Different KPI have different spans (Week, Month, Quarter), and they are at the enterprise to group level.

Because all of these different metrics will be displayed on a common “Report Card” by group we need to pick a single data range to report.  By its nature this report will be used to measure daily performance of staff.

Report format is defined by span so it must be standardized 
[image]

My Question is what span is going to be most useful/appropriate in this situation?  It seems like it should be a week, but good arguments could be made for a month or even three months as well.  Is a week the best choice? Are there studies or solid arguments for a different period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Week is a good interval for such reports, because it provides management with 52 opportunities each year to assess the results and initiate corrective action if required. A monthly window is too long, and daily provides too granular a view - unless you're dealing with many hundreds of transactions per day.

I would like to see your report with activity as shown, as well as some totals and comparative numbers. For example:
 - total for the week
 - month-to-date total
 - percent that Tech 1 closed vs all techs
 - average # of tickets closed over the past 4 weeks (averaging the 4 weekly totals)
 - average # of tickets closed over the past 6 months (averaging the previous 24 weekly totals)

This gives insight into how the tech is performing individually, against the group, and against his own history (is the tech improving?)

Comment: Thank you, that is simular to what I was thinking.  Though I had not thought about including the averages over span.